# Windows 10 file search two folders

Tags: windows, search, windows-10, directory

I'm in document control.
I have to search two folders repeatedly.
Can windows 10 search inside of both folders at the same time?

Glenn. Thanks.

Comment: It would always help to be more specific and to include an example. That's probably why someone gave you -1 and why no one answered sooner.

Answer (score 5):

There are two options:
- search common parent folder and include only results from desired paths
- create custom search, which searches only desired paths

Let's say I have this folder structure:

```
.\temp\A\B\folder1
.\temp\I\J\folder2
.\temp\X\Y\folder3
```

[image]
where each folder contains files named **fileX in FolderY.txt**
Now I want to search for **file1** in folder1 and folder2, but not in any other folders, like folder3

---

- Option 1

Open folder that is common for both subfolders containing searched files. In our example it's folder **temp**.

[image]

And enter this search string: `file1 (folder:(temp\A\B\folder1) OR folder:temp\I\J\folder2)`

[image]

brackets containing OR statement is needed, and brackets around path are optional, if that path does not contain spaces.

This Option is not very optimal if the folder from which you start your search contains many files. Starting this search from C:\ will still search the whole C:\

---

- Option 2

Firstly enter search string including any possible search options, but without folder specification:

[image]

Now click **Search - Save Search** and save the search to a .search-ms file
Open that file in Notepad and close to the end, there will be something like this:
`<include path="::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\C:\temp" attributes="1887437183"/>`
Duplicate the whole tag as many times as needed, while changing path on each to one, in which you want the search to be done.
Save the file, rename as you like, move to any place you like and use it by double-clicking on it.

[image]

- This way, only specified locations are searched, which makes the search fast
- in this screenshot picture, the search-ms is formatted, which is normally not. It doesn't matter if you save it formatted or minified, or if you format just the Scope element, entering each include on a new line
- any search options are also saved to search-ms, like recursive search (Current Folder\All subfolders), date, or file type
- you can also use `<exclude path=` to exclude a path location from search
- you can use `<include knownFolder="<GUID>"` to make locations more generic and portable [Known Folder IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [More about search-ms format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892885(v=vs.85).aspx#savedsearch_full_example)

Answer (score 0):

I created a batch file using option 2.
It allows you to specify a search term and then generate and run an .ms-search file.

You must replace the path "C:\Folder01", "D:\Folder01", "E:\Folder01", "F:\Folder01".

```
 @echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 100) do  (
    set /p searchterm="Enter search: "
    (
        echo ^<?xml version="1.0"?^>
        echo ^<persistedQuery version="1.0"^>
        echo ^<viewInfo viewMode="details" iconSize="16"^>
        echo ^<sortList^>
        echo ^<sort viewField="System.DateModified" direction="descending"/^>
        echo ^</sortList^>
        echo ^</viewInfo^>
        echo ^<query^>
        echo ^<conditions^>
        echo ^<condition type="leafCondition" property="System.Generic.String" operator="wordmatch" propertyType="string" value="!searchterm!" localeName="en-US"^>
        echo ^</condition^>
        echo ^</conditions^>
        echo ^<kindList^>
        echo ^<kind name="item"/^>
        echo ^</kindList^>
        echo ^<scope^>
        echo ^<include path="::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\C:\Folder01" attributes="1887437149"/^>
        echo ^<include path="::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\D:\Folder01" attributes="1887437149"/^>
        echo ^<include path="::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\E:\Folder01" attributes="1887437149"/^>
        echo ^<include path="::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\F:\Folder01" attributes="1887437149"/^>
        echo ^</scope^>
        echo ^</query^>
        echo ^</persistedQuery^>
    ) > GeneratedMoviesSearch.search-ms
    GeneratedMoviesSearch.search-ms
)
```